# Evaluate the limit as $x$ approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to \infty } \frac{2x-\cos x}{3x+\cos x} $$

Anyone can guide me for this question?
Appreciate your help . Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply by $1/x$, and hence, as outlined by the other response, the problem reduces to show what $\frac{ \cos x }{ x} $ approaches to as $x \to \infty $.

Hint:  Since $| \cos y | \leq 1 $ for all $y$, we have

$$ \frac{-1}{x} \leq \frac{ \cos x }{x} \leq \frac{1}{x} $$

Now, apply the Squeeze Rule.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\dfrac{2x-\cos x}{3x+\cos x}=\dfrac{2-\frac{\cos x}{x}}{3+\frac{\cos x}{x}}$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty } {{2x-\cos(x)} \over {3x+\cos(x)}} $$
$$=\lim_{x \to {\infty} } {{2 - \cos(x)/x} \over {3 +\cos(x)/x}}$$
$$(1) \quad ={{2 - \lim_{x \to {\infty}} \left( {{\cos(x)} \over x} \right)} \over {3 +\lim_{x \to {\infty}} \left( {{\cos(x)} \over x} \right)}} $$

Cosine can only take on values from 1 to -1 so it has finite bound. In the limit, it's divided by an infinite number so the limit of...

$$\lim_{x \to {\infty}} {{\cos(x)} \over {x}}=0$$

Thus, (1) equals $ { 2 \over 3}$ and therefore,

$$\lim_{x\to \infty } {{2x-\cos(x)} \over {3x+\cos(x)}} ={ 2 \over 3}$$

Answer (score 2):

by using long division
$$\frac{2x-\cos x}{3x+\cos x}=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{5/3\cos x}{3x+\cos x}$$

so the limit is
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{2x-\cos x}{3x+\cos x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{2}{3}-\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{5/3*\cos x}{3x+\cos x}=\frac{2}{3}-0=\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: Probably there is a serial downvoter who downvoted all the correct hints and answers.

Comment: Why the downvote???

Comment: Probably some "joker" that decided to have what he thinks a bit of fun...

Comment: but where is the control???

Comment: Other users than the downvoter themself can only speculate what was the reason for the downvote. But if you wish to discuss the reason for the downvote, there is a [chatroom explicitly for this purpose](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21818649#21818649).

Answer (score 0):

If we factor an $x$ from your rational function, then we have

$$\frac{2x-cos(x)}{3x+cos(x)} = \frac{x\left(2-\frac{cos(x)}{x}\right)}{x\left(3+\frac{cos(x)}{x}\right)} = \frac{2-\frac{cos(x)}{x}}{3+\frac{cos(x)}{x}}$$

You may recall the identity $\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{cos(x)}{x}\right) = 0$, which can easily be confirmed using L'Hopital's rule for indeterminates of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Evaluating the limit, we have

$$lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{2x-cos(x)}{3x+cos(x)}\right) = lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{2-\frac{cos(x)}{x}}{3+\frac{cos(x)}{x}}\right) = \frac{2-lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{cos(x)}{x}\right)}{3+lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{cos(x)}{x}\right)} = \frac{2}{3}$$

which is the solution to the problem.